# A formula for radius of convergence of derivative of power series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I am looking proof for radius of convergence of power series and its derivative. For it, I needed following lemma, whose proof I have written below, and want to know if it is correct.

> Lemma: Let $\{ a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ be sequences of **positive** reals, with following conditions:
>   $$
> \lim \sup a_n =a \mbox{ and } \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} b_n=b>0.$$
>   Then $\lim\sup (a_nb_n)=ab.$

**Proof.** Since $b>0$, choose $\epsilon>0$ so small that $0<b-\epsilon$. Then  there exists $N\ge 1$ such that 
$(b-\epsilon) < b_n < (b+\epsilon)$ for all $n\ge N$. Therefore for $n\ge N$,
 $$a_n(b-\epsilon) < a_nb_n < a_n(b+\epsilon).$$
Now taking $\lim \sup$, and *noting that all quantities are positive* (is this necessary?) we get 
$$\lim\sup a_n(b-\epsilon) \le \lim\sup (a_nb_n) \le \lim\sup a_n(b+\epsilon).$$
Since $(b-\epsilon)$ and $(b+\epsilon)$ are positive, we can take them out from $\lim \sup$ in first and last term, and we get 
$$(b-\epsilon) a =(b-\epsilon)\lim\sup a_n \le \lim\sup (a_nb_n) \le (b+\epsilon)\lim\sup a_n \le (b+\epsilon)a.$$
Therefore we ge desired result.

Comment: Yes, perfect reasoning.

Comment: Great proof. Your comment on everything being positive is a good one; for example, let $a = -1, b = -1,$ and $\epsilon = \tfrac 12$. Then $a(b-\epsilon) = \tfrac 32 \not \le \tfrac 12 = a(b+\epsilon)$. You would have to do a bit more casework or take absolute values